# How do I modify a UserDataSource once it is retrieved via a service in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am trying to modify an Angular UserDataSource, to add a row to it once the data is returned from an API call (inside the finalize method). The data source works fine, but the new row is not added. What am I doing wrong?

```
export class CompanyDataSource implements DataSource<vwCompany> {

private CompanyModelsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<vwCompany[]>([]);
private loadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
public loading$ = this.loadingSubject.asObservable();
get data() { return this.CompanyModelsSubject.value; }

....

loadData(lgid) {     
    this.loadingSubject.next(true);
    return this.svc.getCompanies(lgid.toString()).pipe(
        catchError(x => throwError('company connect error: ' + x)), //not sure if this will ever be displayed
        finalize(() => {

            //add sum row to company table
            let sum = new vwCompany();
            sum.awsCoId = this.CompanyModelsSubject.value[0].awsCoId;
            sum.coName = "SUMS";

            this.CompanyModelsSubject.value.forEach((x: vwCompany) => sum.dropoffInUse += x.dropoffInUse);

            this.CompanyModelsSubject.value.push(sum);

            this.loadingSubject.next(false);
            //console.log('dataSource update complete')
        })
    ).subscribe(y => {
        this.CompanyModelsSubject.next(y);
        //console.log('updated datasource to length: ' + y.length + ' data() returns length' + this.data.length);
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're accessing the subject value in weird and ineffective manner. rxjs is all about being functional and reactive, but you're accessing it in a stateful manner, instead use it's operators correctly to do this, by just using the map operator...

```
loadData(lgid) {     
    this.loadingSubject.next(true);
    return this.svc.getCompanies(lgid.toString()).pipe(
        catchError(x => throwError('company connect error: ' + x)), //not sure if this will ever be displayed
        map((CompanyModels) => {

            //add sum row to company table
            let sum = new vwCompany();
            sum.awsCoId = CompanyModels[0].awsCoId;
            sum.coName = "SUMS";

            CompanyModels.forEach((x: vwCompany) => sum.dropoffInUse += x.dropoffInUse);

            CompanyModels.push(sum);

            return CompanyModels;
        })
    ).subscribe(y => {
        this.CompanyModelsSubject.next(y);
        this.loadingSubject.next(false); // do this here
        //console.log('updated datasource to length: ' + y.length + ' data() returns length' + this.data.length);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new object everytime

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="getUpdatedData()" >


getUpdatedData(){
this.newData = {...this.oldData}; // do your modifications here
return this.newData;
}
```